# Plugin with editable link element

Tags: django, django-cms

While implementing a Django CMS site, I’m a little stuck on link management (internal or external). In my project I have a specific box plugin the operator is to use quite often. I added screenshots of edit dialog and box rendering at the end of the question.

The edit dialog is nice, but right now the button is just a char field. So the link selection, either to a page within Django CMS or to an external URL, is missing. I looked for a link field, but until now I am lost.

How to add the feature to let the operator select an internal or external link ?

The plugin consists of these parts:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField

class CardPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256,default='')
    description = HTMLField(configuration='CKEDITOR_SETTINGS',
                            default='')
    button = models.CharField(max_length=256,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

cms_plugins.py

```
class CardCMSPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = CardPlugin
    name = 'Card'
    render_template = "card-default.html"
```

card-default.html

```
{% load cms_tags %}
<section class="card card--primary-light">
  <div class="card__inner">
    <div class="card__content">
      <div class="card__text">
        <h2 class="card__title">
            {{ instance.title }}
        </h2>
        <p class="card__description">
            {{ instance.description }}
        </p>
      </div>
      {% if instance.button %}
      <div class="card__buttons">
            <a href="#0" class="button button--primary-inverse">{{ instance.button }}</a>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

the rendered box

[image: The rendered box]

The plugin edit dialog looks like this:

[image: the plugin edit dialog]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at adding the djangocms-link plugin as a child plugin. It's a very good plugin to link to internal CMS pages or external addresses. That way you could drop the `button` field from your model, and instead render the child plugins in your template.

The docs on [nested plugins](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/custom_plugins.html#nested-plugins) would be a good read.

Your plugin definition would become something like this;

```
class ParentCMSPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    render_template = 'parent.html'
    name = 'Parent'
    model = ParentPlugin
    allow_children = True
    child_classes = ['LinkPlugin']
```

To render child plugins you'd then do this with your template;

```
{% load cms_tags %}
<section class="card card--primary-light">
    <div class="card__inner">
        <div class="card__content">
            <div class="card__text">
                <h2 class="card__title">
                    {{ instance.title }}
                </h2>
                <p class="card__description">
                    {{ instance.description }}
                </p>
            </div>
            {% for plugin in instance.child_plugin_instances %}
                {% render_plugin plugin %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And that would use the default render template for the child plugin. If the default didn't match the styling etc, you could handle the rendering in the template instead of using `render_plugin` or subclass the `LinkPlugin` to work how you want, or extend it's attributes etc.

Some further consideration should do to dropping your description field in favour of also using the `TextPlugin` as a child, because the CMS text plugin can nest plugins within itself and is something I'd always use over an `HTMLField`.

Further still, if you're developing applications hooked in to CMS, take a look at [`PlaceholderFields`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/placeholders.html?highlight=placeholderfield) which allow you to create placeholders in your own models to hold & use the CMS plugins that you can use in CMS pages. That gets really good for things like news apps or blog style content etc.

Comment: I tried the child plugin solution beforehand. I had the Text plugin as a child for the box plugin. But this seems somehow superficial. Right now adding a new box is done in a very quick way: adding the box and tabbing through three fields and hit enter. Done. Adding children is really a burden to the user and makes the structure more complicated while not gaining anything. So there isn't something like a LinkField or whatever ?

I don't see the PlaceholderFields to apply to my question, since it is a CMS Plugin, right ?

Comment: It's not a burden, it's just a more typical way of working with django-cms. You could add a `LinkField` to your model, then `instance.linkfield` would be the `href` attr of your button. The trouble you have then though is you don't have the power of the [link plugin](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link) to link to pages or external URLs, or additional settings like classes or templates. And `PlaceholderField` is just something you might want to look into, me being helpful incase you're not familiar with it.

Comment: But I am using the HTMLField provided by djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields in my model and have the full fledged editor in my plugin. This seems so powerful. Is this considered bad design in Django CMS  ? What's the point then of having plugins, when one has to disperse his needs into smaller unrelated bits at the end all over again ?

Comment: You're right, you do get the full editor, but you don't get nested plugins. If you look at the Text plugin, it has a 'CMS plugins' menu item. You don't get that when you use the `HTMLField` on your own model because it uses the placeholder. Anyway, to get your link to work, have you tried child link plugins?

Comment: The link works but is no longer styled correctly, because the link is not rendered with the correct class. Is it possible to provide that styling through the parent plugin ?

Comment: If it's only class, you can provide attributes in the settings for the link plugin. If it's more than that, render it with your own markup in the template

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. That helped !

Comment: Thanks for the great discussion! I appreciate the ``PlaceholderField`` approach. __Is it possible to prepopulate the ``PlaceholderField``s?__ In this example I could think of having two placeholder fields, say ``description`` and ``button``. When creating a plugin object, I would like to prepopulate ``description`` field with a Text plugin and the ``button`` field with a Link plugin.